# SMTP server error: Verification failed for 550-No Such User Here 550 Sender verify failed

Tags: wordpress, smtp, hosting

I'm using 
[Configure SMTP](http://coffee2code.com/wp-plugins/configure-smtp/) plugin for wordpress, when I used it in a local server (localhost) it works properly and send me the test email which confirms that it is working. But when I used it in a hosting site (I used Hostgator) it gives me an STMP error. [image]

What is the possible cause of this error? and what is the possible solution?

Thank you.

Comment: here's a scenario - it means that with hostgator the account you are using to perform certain actions doesnt have the need permissions. so i would check the permissions on any of the files or directories this plugin uses, it may need write permissions and could just have read.

Comment: There would be multiple possibilities based on you question.  You may want to elaborate on your question such as whether or not it is actually able to communicate under the port & server settings.  And if you have tried a different server and a different email all together to see if it will at least function another way.

Comment: If you host your site with hosting provider, they have their own setting on mail server. So, I suggest you to ask it to your provider, HostGator. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the second error, and the words "verification failed", and "sender verify" failed, my guess would be that you have not set up SMTP authentication correctly.  You are relaying your mail through Hostgator, so they may have specific hostnames / ports that you need to authenticate correctly with to get your mail to flow.  I'd suggest syncing with Hostgator on this.